# Quickblox ios crash on dismiss view

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have been using the QuickBlox SDK. When the user hangs up the call or rejects the call on the sessionDidClose callback i dismiss the viewcontroller that contains the video tracks. This causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at EAGLContext setCurrentContext.

Any suggestions?